# Sharepoint Search for Keyword

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

The company I work for is currently re branding and changing it's name. We have a Massive share point intranet site and I need to be able to search every page and locate all instances where our old name has been used - so I can submit this to management to get changed.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?
I've not got access to the central farm and anything I install can only be on my computer.

So far I've tried using sharepoint designer and ctrl + f to search for the term but it only searches that page - I need a farm wide search.

Any help would be appreciated as this is a MAHOOOOSIVE project and I've been left on my tod to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option I can think of is painful. You would have to write a powershell script to do a search and replace for the company name in your SQL content database(s). This could be a problem if you dont have access to the database(s). Each site collection could have a different content db too.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a PowerShell script for  iterating through each and every web applications in your farm , site collections, subsites, doc libs, lists and folder and items such that you can search for name of your current company name and list out /dump that into a excel or  txt/csv file.

From here, you can further manipulate based on your requirements .